# Adequate software to draw grids

Tags: draw

Do you know any software (online or not) easy to understand and appropriate to create this kind of plots?

[image: 1]

I would like the image to be vectorized, can write subindices, arrows, dots and so on to explain numerical stencils and grids.

I am using Windows 7

PS: Any moderator could please add the right tags and delete this PS?

Comment: in an app, or a webpage, on a sheet of paper?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. ... That said, looking at the font this looks like it's drawn with TeX. Maybe you could ask on [tex.se] how it was done.

Comment: @Alnitak I said it, online or using a programme